# Why is it when Custom UIView loads itself from a NIB but is also embedded in another NIB I get infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a problem with a custom uiview (MyCustomView) loading its view from a NIB (MyCustomView.xib).

The problem is the MyCustomView is reused in other XIBs so awakeFromNib is called.
The CustomView.xib also contains an instance of MyCustomView so loadNibNamed in MyCustomView.awakeFromNib goes into infinite loop

im getting infinite loop as:

```
SomeVC.xib
+ calls MyCustomView awakeFromNib
++ which calls loadNibNamed: MyCustomView.nib
+++++ but top level View is also instance of MyCustomView
....so awakeFromNib: goes into infinite loop
```

Im just wondering if when a custom view loads its self from a nib then top level UIView shouldnt be instance of MyCustomView?
If so how do I wire up outlet/actions (do I make MyCustomView the files owner instead?)

anyway cheers

```
LONG EXPLANATION:
```

I have a row of buttons which I want to reuse on a number of screens.
So I created a custom view

```
@interface ScreenMenuButtonsView : UIView
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonHome;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonMyMusic;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonStore;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonSocial;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonSettings;

@end
```

I wanted to layout the view in IB so I created a NIB

```
ScreenMenuButtonsView_iPad.xib

Files Owner: no set NSObject
VIEW: ScreenMenuButtonsView
+ UIButton
+ UIButton
+ UIButton
```

I want the custom view to load its own NIB internally and I used the example from
http://nathanhjones.com/2011/02/20/creating-reusable-uiviews-with-a-drop-shadow-tutorial/
http://nathanhjones.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ReusableTableHeaders.zip

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    //self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; // not needed - thanks ddickison
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView"
                        owner:self
                        options:nil];

        [self release]; // release object before reassignment to avoid leak - thanks ddickison
        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.40;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Which is ok except this presumes you call initWithFrame somewhere to instantiate the CustomView.
The HeaderView example calls it like this:

```
// load the header - this could be done in viewWillAppear as well
HeaderView *header = [[HeaderView alloc] 
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
header.lblTitle.text = @"That. Just. Happened.";
tblData.tableHeaderView = header;
[header release];
```

I wanted to be able to use my custom view class in any other XIB

HomeScreenViewController.xib

```
Files Owner: HomeScreenViewController
View:
+ ....other controls
+ ScreenMenuButtonsView
```

The problem is when HomeScreenViewController is loaded it calls awakeFromNib on my customView:

so I moved the nib loading out initWithFrame and into a method called setupView and called it from initWithFrame AND awakeFromNib

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ( ( self = [super initWithFrame: frame] ) )
    {
        [self setUpView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setUpView];
}

- (void) setUpView{

    if (self) {


        NSArray* nibViewsArray = nil;
        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            //IPAD
            nibViewsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScreenMenuButtonsView_iPad"
                                                          owner:self
                                                        options:nil];    
...
}
```

My problem is that when HomeScreenViewController.xib is loaded:

HomeScreenViewController.xib

```
Files Owner: HomeScreenViewController
View:
+ ....other controls
+ ScreenMenuButtonsView
```

It tries to create ScreenMenuButtonsView and because its in a NIB 
it calls
ScreenMenuButtonsView awakeFromNib

BUT in here I call loadNibNamed:

```
- (void) setUpView{
    _viewSetupAlready = TRUE;
    //http://nathanhjones.com/2011/02/20/creating-reusable-uiviews-with-a-drop-shadow-tutorial/
    //self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; // not needed - thanks ddickison
    if (self) {
        NSArray* nibViewsArray = nil;
        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            //IPAD
            nibViewsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScreenMenuButtonsView_iPad"
                                                          owner:self
                                                        options:nil];            
        }else{
            //IPHONE
            nibViewsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScreenMenuButtonsView_iPhone"
                                                     owner:self
                                                   options:nil];
        }
        if(nibViewsArray){
            //[self release];   // release object before reassignment to avoid leak - thanks ddickison                
            UIView * myView  = [nibViewsArray objectAtIndex: 0];

            //Check the top level object in NIB is same type as this custom class
            //if wrong you probably forgot to use correct NIB name in loadNibNamed:
            if([myView isMemberOfClass:[self class]]){

                self = (ScreenMenuButtonsView *)myView; 

            }else{
                NSLog(@"ERROR:top level view is not same type as custom class - are you loading the correct nib filename in loadNibNamed:\n%@", myView);
            }
        }else{
            NSLog(@"ERROR:nibViewsArray is nil");
        }
    }
}
```

loadNibName: load

```
ScreenMenuButtonsView_iPad.xib

Files Owner: no set NSObject
VIEW: ScreenMenuButtonsView
+ UIButton
+ UIButton
+ UIButton
```

But top view is ScreenMenuButtonsView 
so creates a new instance and calls awakeFromNib
and I get infinite loop.

I know why the loops occurring and instance on ScreenMenuButtonsView is loading another instance from the xib.

My question is in

ScreenMenuButtonsView_iPad.xib

```
Files Owner: no set NSObject
VIEW: ScreenMenuButtonsView
+ UIButton
+ UIButton
+ UIButton
```

should I change 
 VIEW: UIView

but what about outlets and actions for the button:
should I change 
Files Owner: no set NSObject

to be the view class

Files Owner: ScreenMenuButtonsView

Comment: fixed it myself. in XIB Files Owner: MyCustomView(UIView). TOP LEVEL VIEW is UIView. Add subview under this. Add outlets to MyCustomView and connect in the NIB. loadNibNamed: owner= self called in MyCustoMView awakeFromNib will connect outlets. To get Top Level View:UIView in Nib into MyCustomView use [self addSubview:topLevelViewInNib. Dont use self = (MyCustomView *)topLevelViewInNib.

Comment: DO NOT HAVE INSTANCE of MyCustomView in NIB loaded in MyCustomView.awakeFromNib [if you MyCustoView is embedded in another nib] this will cause infinite loop on awakeFromNib. OuterView.xib.awakeFromNib > embedded MyCustomView.xib awakeFromNib >> loadNibNamed: MYCustomView.nib > awakefromNib (infinite loop). put break point on loadNibNamed and watch stack. without break point you just get EXC_BAD_ACCESS looks like pointer error